# Does Simple Injector have a feature like Autofac Factory Delegates?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, simple-injector

Consider the scenario where a service's constructor has a mix of parameters: some you want the container to resolve based on whatever you registered, and some you want the consumer of the service to provide.

With Autofac, one may add a Factory delegate to a service as follows (examples below are taken from their [documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html)) :

```
public class Shareholding
{
  // We don't have to add the quote service to the factory delegate.
  public delegate Shareholding Factory(string symbol, uint holding);

  // Parameters in the constructor that don't show up in
  // the delegate will come from the appropriate lifetime scope.
  public Shareholding(string symbol, uint holding, IQuoteService quoteService)
  {
...
  }
```

You register the service "normally":

```
builder.RegisterType<Shareholding>();
```

Autofac does some magic, and now the Factory is requestable on consumers. Autofac will supply the missing parameters (IQuoteService in this case) with whatever is registered, if possible, and provide a new instance each time the factory is invoked, e.g.:

```
public class Portfolio
{
  private readonly Shareholding.Factory _shareHoldingFactory;

  private readonly List<Shareholding> _holdings = new List<Shareholding>();

  public Portfolio(Shareholding.Factory shareholdingFactory)
  {
    _shareHoldingFactory = shareholdingFactory;
  }

  public void Add(string symbol, uint holding)
  {
    _holdings.Add(_shareHoldingFactory(symbol, holding));
  }
}
```

Does Simple Injector have something similar to this? I have gone around in circles considering and trying a few things:

1. Registering an, e.g., `Func<string, uint, QuoteService>` won't work because then I'll need to request `Func<string, uint, QuoteService>` on my consumers instead of just QuoteService.Factory, which will be annoying if it's used in more than one place and the parameters are changed.
2. I don't really want to create factory wrappers for all my services. Having been spoilt by Autofac, this just seems like too much overhead now.
3. The `Register<TService>(Func<TService> instanceCreator)` overload won't work because the Func doesn't take parameters and there isn't an overload for one that does (right?)

I feel like I'm missing something obvious because this is such a useful feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Simple Injector have something similar to this?

No, it doesn't contain such feature out-of-the-box. It does so because Simple Injector discourages a design were constructors mix runtime data with Volatile Dependencies. You can find the reasoning [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

To take your `Shareholding` as an example, depending on the role of this class, you can:

1. Remove `symbol` and `holding` from its constructor and pass it through using one of `Shareholding`'s public methods. This is especially useful when `Shareholding` is an application component; i.e. a class that mainly contains behavior.
2. Remove the `IQuoteService` Volatile Dependency from `Shareholding`'s constructor and pass it through one of its public methods. In other words, use Method Injection rather than Constructor Injection. This is especially useful when `Shareholding` itself is a Domain Entity, where `symbol` and `holding` are properties of the entity, and where there is a Domain Method that requires the `IQuoteService` Volatile Dependency to function.

Although Simple Injector does not contain this feature out-of-the-box -and I would generally advise against it- it is certainly possible to add this feature on top of Simple Injector. There are [examples](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector.CodeSamples/AutomaticParameterizedFactoryExtensions.cs) in Simple Injector's Code Samples project that demonstrate ways to achieve this.

And of course you can register the [delegates by hand](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates), which is not that much work if you have just a few of these types of registrations. For instance:

```cs
container.RegisterInstance<Shareholding.Factory>((symbol, holding) =>
    new Shareholding(symbol, holding, container.GetInstance<IQuoteService>()));
```

Comment: Hi @Steven, thanks for your answer! In your point 1, the first sentence ends with "or". Was there something additional to follow?

And thanks for your final suggestion. I believe that wouldn't be ideal for me because of what I mention in my point 1 (consumers would need to request that exact Func instead of an abstraction such as Shareholding.Factory). Correct?

Comment: Hi Gusmally, there was indeed some additional text after the "or", which I removed because it just complicated things, without adding much. I accidentally forgot to remove the or as well.

Comment: No, you can register and resolve the `Shareholding.Factory` delegate directly, so there's no need to reference the complete `Func<string, unit, Shareholding>` signature, if you wish. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Steven, thanks for the updates. Also, the blog post you linked is very well written and interesting : ) thanks for taking the time to explain all this stuff.

Comment: You're more than welcome.